# Pandas - Count Vectorize Series of Transaction Activities by User

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Trying to accomplish the below, but in Pandas and optimally as this is abysmally slow on 1,000,000 records using my current numpy-ish approach

Sample of data in csv:

```
03530c9197f5845,5/9/14,EmailOpen
03530c9197f5845,5/12/14,EmailOpen
03530c9197f5845,5/19/14,EmailOpen
03530c9197f5845,5/20/14,EmailOpen 
03530c9197f5845,5/27/14,EmailOpen
03530c9197f5845,5/29/14,EmailOpen
03530c9197f5845,6/2/14,PageView
03530c9197f5845,6/2/14,WebVisit  
...
```

where first column is user hash, second column is event date and third column is event type

Example output needed:

```
03530c9197f5845, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5
89430s7897r3821, 1, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0
...
```

where the first column is the userid, and the proceeding columns are the counts of each unique event type (there are around 8 event types) as features for training.

The code below accomplishes what I'm looking for, but slowly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv').as_matrix()
usersData = [v[0] for v in data]
actionsData = [v[2] for v in data]

actions = set(actionsData)
users = set(usersData)

target = np.zeros((len(users), len(actions)))
for i, user in enumerate(users):
    for j, action in enumerate(actions):
        val = len([d for d in data if d[0] == user and d[2] == action])
        target[i][j] = val
```

Tried using groupby and count_values on a dataframe, but stuck on expanding the results to a count vector a.k.a. the count columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pivot_table` function in `pandas` should do what you want. For instance:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', header=None)
frame.columns = ['user_id', 'date', 'event_type']
frame_pivoted = frame.pivot_table(
    index='user_id', columns='event_type', aggfunc='count'
)
```

In general, using vectorized Pandas functions is much faster than `for` loops, although I haven't compared the performance in your specific case.